# Access main window DOM from background task

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to build a test tool that will allow me to access the window DOM and allow me to programmatically fill out forms, press submit buttons etc. Assume its a web DOM. Can jquery (or other js library) reside in the background (assume its a different application) and provide me control/access to the main window DOM ??

Any ideas/concepts/pointers/issues would be appreciated.

thanks,wk

Comment: Current javascript is single threaded if you can use HTML5 you can use webworkers

Comment: I thought webworkers didn't have access to the DOM. How would I use a web worker to fill out a html5 form ?